# transform ec2 tags with jq and node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, jq

I need to transform this ec2 tags (array)

```
[ 
    { Key: 'Name', Value: 'xxx' },
    { Key: 'role', Value: 'yyy' } 
]
```

to

```
{ 
 name : 'xxx',
 role : 'yyy'
}
```

using jq and node.js. Could you help please
regards

Comment: Did you mean JSON parser jq or jquery?

Comment: If you mean it with `jq`, the JSON is not in a valid syntax to be parsed. The keys/values should be double quoted

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`Object.fromEntries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries) like this:

```js
const tags = [ 
    { Key: 'Name', Value: 'xxx' },
    { Key: 'role', Value: 'yyy' } 
];


const obj = Object.fromEntries(tags.map(({ Key, Value }) => [Key, Value]));

console.log(obj);
```